# parent model id not passing, using ryan bates nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm trying to use Ryan Bates' excellent 'nested forms' to create the following->

When creating a new 'Job', a user will have the option to write in multiple bullet points about it, and multiple 'Roles'

Here's how the models are set up :

**Job Model**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: jobs
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  job_title      :string(255)
#  job_summary    :string(255)
#  qualifications :string(255)
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :job_title, presence: true 
    validates :job_summary, presence: true
    validates :qualifications, presence: true 

    has_many :bullets, dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :roles, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bullets, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:bullet].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:role_title].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
        #lambda { |a| a[:bullet].blank? } makes sure that on edit, if a value is left blank, then it doesn't save it

end
```

**Bullet Model**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: bullets
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  job_id     :integer
#  bullet     :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Bullet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job
    validates :job_id, presence: true
    validates :bullet, presence: true
end
```

**Role Model**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: roles
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  job_id     :integer
#  role_title :string(255)
#  role_desc  :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job

    validates :job_id, presence: true
    validates :role_title, presence: true
    validates :role_desc,  presence: true
end
```

**Jobs Controller :**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:new, :create, :update, :show, :edit, :destroy] # index, at least partially is available to all viewers
  before_action :admin_user, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :create, :destroy] # only admins can make jobs

  def new 
    @job = Job.new
    3.times {
        @job.bullets.build
        @job.roles.build
    }
  end

  def create
     @job = Job.new(job_params)
     if @job.save
       redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :success => "Job created!" }
     else
       render 'new'
     end
  end

  def job_params 
    params.require(:job).permit(:job_title, :job_summary, :qualifications,
                                 bullets_attributes: [:id, :bullet, :_destroy],
                                 roles_attributes: [:id, :role_title,:role_desc, :_destroy])
  end

end
```

**Jobs/New View**

```
<% provide(:title, "Publish a new job") %>
<%= nested_form_for @job do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :job_title %>
  <%= f.text_field :job_title %>

  <div style="margin-left:30px">
      <%= f.fields_for :bullets do |bullet_form| %>
        <%= bullet_form.label :bullet %>
        <%= bullet_form.text_field :bullet %>
        <%= bullet_form.link_to_remove "Remove this bullet" %>
      <% end %>
      <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a Bullet", :bullets %></p>
  </div>


  <%= f.label :job_summary %>
  <%= f.text_area :job_summary %>

  <%= f.label :qualifications %>
  <%= f.text_area :qualifications %>

  <div style="margin-left:30px">
      <%= f.fields_for :roles do |role_form| %>
        <%= role_form.label :role_title %>
        <%= role_form.text_field :role_title %>
        <%= role_form.label :role_desc %>
        <%= role_form.text_field :role_desc %>
        <%= role_form.link_to_remove "Remove this Role" %>
      <% end %>
      <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a Role", :roles %></p>
  </div>



  <%= f.submit "Publish the Job", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

Alas, it looks like I'm doing it incorrectly. When I try to create a new job, I get the error :

```
* Bullets job can't be blank
* Roles job can't be blank
```

It seems to me like the info for job_id is not passing through the nested forms.

What you think is happening, and ideas about making this work would be greatly appreciated :)

**Logs**

Here are some logs to make it a bit clearer:

1) When I submit the form, choosing only 1 bullet I get the following parameters in development:

```
 --- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: ezgktBZjcrdI6nMTro8Aqd0Djs2k3M+HFAdACrxajS8=
job: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  job_title: Job Title example
  bullets_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
    '0': !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      bullet: Example bullet
      _destroy: 'false'
  job_summary: Job Summary Example
  qualifications: Example Qualifications here
  roles_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
    '1387448871560': !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      role_title: Example Role Name
      role_desc: Example Role Description
      _destroy: 'false'
commit: Publish the Job
action: create
controller: jobs
```

On my Rails Server, this is what it's saying ->

```
Started POST "/jobs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-19 14:28:01 +0400
Processing by JobsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ezgktBZjcrdI6nMTro8Aqd0Djs2k3M+HFAdACrxajS8=", "job"=>{"job_title"=>"Job Title example", "bullets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"bullet"=>"Example bullet", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "job_summary"=>"Job Summary Example", "qualifications"=>"Example Qualifications here", "roles_attributes"=>{"1387448871560"=>{"role_title"=>"Example Role Name", "role_desc"=>"Example Role Description", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Publish the Job"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '449addc616f3035c031b3220404a4d5eb5351c74' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered jobs/new.html.erb within layouts/application (15.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 101ms (Views: 32.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: You should post your log for this request

Comment: Hi Rich, just updated the post with some logs. Let me know if there's more info I can provide.

Comment: Also of note, from the google searches, people who had a similar problem to me all seem to have some sort of issue with associations. I.e they had has_one, instead of belongs_to etc. However, looking at my models the wrong thing doesn't jump out to me

Comment: Thanks for update - An immediate observation is: no `roles_attributes` are being passed

Comment: Hi Rich, for the sake of the example, I chose to only write in one bullet, with no roles. Will also update now to make the logs a bit more representative of the whole question

Comment: Ahhh the old `child_index => Time.now.to_i` trick :D

Comment: Aand thank you for being a mentor! :).

Comment: lol I am just someone who loves RoR!

Comment: Writing answer for you

Comment: Updated answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've posted, there are several issues which could be causing the problem

---

**Strong Params**

```
def job_params 
    params.require(:job).permit(:job_title, :job_summary, :qualifications,
                                 bullets_attributes: [:bullet],
                                 roles_attributes: [:role_title,:role_desc])
end
```

I don't know why you've called your columns `role_title` and `role_desc`, but it's better to call the columns only by their actual name (`title` and `desc`)

It's basically because if you load `@role`, it's much more efficient to write `@role.title` rather than `@role.role_title`. The same for your other tables

You may wish to update your schemas to reflect that

---

**ActiveRecord Build**

Second problem is you're building your new ActiveRecord objects 3 times:

```
 def new 
    @job = Job.new
    3.times {
        @job.bullets.build
        @job.roles.build
    }
 end
```

This would be okay if you wanted to send 3 objects, but you only have 1. And I know you've done it so you can add extra fields (I'll explain that in a second)

You should change to this:

```
 def new 
    @job = Job.new
    @job.bullets.build
    @job.roles.build
  end
```

I believe this is your main issue actually - if you build the objects & they don't get populated, they are blank, no?

I would only declare the objects I wanted to show up front, and add the extras when required

---

**Adding Fields**

If you wish to add fields on the fly (with Ajax), I would highly recommend [this tutorial](http://pikender.in/2013/04/20/child-forms-using-fields_for-through-ajax-rails-way/). It uses the same principles as Ryan Bates' method, but is much cleaner & adds the objects when required. I can talk about this via chat if you wanted

Comment: Hi Ryan, okay this is making sense. I went ahead and removed the builds, and am updating the data schema right now. 

I'm using the nested_form gem from Ryan, which essentially is handling all of the ajax. The reason I was doing the build, was to initially show about 3 for each one, and then if the user wanted more, or wanted to delete some, he could do so. reject if in the attributes should remove any submit that is blank. 

But, still I'm not quite sure what it's not taking in the new job_id as the job_id for each child model. Thanks for the help, and will look at tutorial :)

Comment: No problem - I don't think you need to see whether it takes the `job_id` param to the child model; it does it in the backend through the association. Let me know if this stuff works for you, otherwise we can work to fix it

Comment: Auff, wasn't as interesting as I though. Okay, back to tutorial :)